# на windows 7 не отображаются шрифты на сайте

Tags: html, css

очень странно, на windows 7 вообще ни в одном браузере нет текста (не распознается шрифт). После отключения font-family текст появляется. Шрифты подключены в формате woff, woff2

```
html, body {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Lato-Regular";
    background: #eef9f9;
    color: #000;
}
```

вот на всякий случай ссылка на сайт

https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/vakansiya_stomatolog/

Comment: все грузится и читается. Включите инструменты разработчика в браузере, закладка сеть и посмотрите грузятся ли шрифты. Возможно их блокирует какой-то хитрый антивирус

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше использовать шрифты с https://fonts.google.com/

Если нет полного набора, то лучше качать с официального сайта шрифта, там есть и обновления, в которых и решаются проблемы отображения(мне помогло - просто заменил файлы шрифтов):
http://www.latofonts.com/